# Creating Batch Files with PostgreSQL \copy Command in Jetbrains Datagrip

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I'm familiarizing myself with the standalone version of Datagrip and having a bit of trouble understanding the different approaches to composing SQL via console, external files, scratch files, etc.

I'm managing, referencing the documentation, and am happy to figure things out as such.

However, I'm trying to ingest CSV data into tables via batch files using the Postgres `\copy` command. Datagrip will execute this command without error but no data is being populated.

This is my syntax, composed and ran in the console view:

```
\copy tablename from 'C:\Users\username\data_file.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' csv;
```

Note that the data is tab-separated and stored in a .txt file.

I'm able to use the import functions of Datagrip (via context menu) just fine but I'd like to understand how to issue commands to do similarly.

Comment: I am not fully understanding what this question has to do with [tag:batch-file]s.  I don't see any code related to it.

Comment: Different approaches to composing SQL are also well-explained in this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2019/01/30/working-with-files-in-datagrip/

Answer (score 1):

`\copy` is a command of the command-line PostgreSQL client `psql`.

I doubt that Datagrip invokes `psql`, so it won't be able to use `\copy` or any other “backslash command”.

You probably have to use [Datagrip's import facilities](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html). Or you start using `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but what about the SQL COPY command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html ?

How can I run something like that with datagrip ?

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_json(values text) ON COMMIT DROP;
COPY temp_json FROM 'MY_FILE.JSON';
SELECT values->>'aJsonField' as f
FROM (select values::json AS values FROM temp_json) AS a;
COMMIT;
```

I try to replace 'MY_FILE.JSON' with full path, parameter (?), I put it in sql directory etc.

The data grip answer is :

```
[2021-05-05 10:30:45] [58P01] ERROR: could not open file '...' for reading : No such file or directory
```

**EDIT** :
I know why. RTFM! -_-

> COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.

Sorry.....